# How to solve this integral involving a partial derivative?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I have the following integral:

\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} ||\ \partial_x (\int_{0}^{t}f(x(s))ds)|| \,dxds
\end{equation}

All I'm asking is where can I go from here? Can I move the partial derivative inside the right-most integral to get
\begin{equation}
 \int_{0}^{t} \int_{\mathbb{R}} ||\ \int_{0}^{t}f'(x(s))ds\;|| \,dxds
\end{equation}

All advice appreciated!

Comment: What is $x(s)$?

Comment: It hasn't been specified to me, are we required to know the explicit form of x(s) before we can move on?

Comment: Yes you need to know what is $x(s)$ before you can even decide if your integral has a meaning. It has to be a typo because as it is now written $x$ is a function but $\mathbb R$ is not a function set